# Objective-C Rest Response

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, rest

I am using a Web Service written in PHP that checks a HTTP Request sent by my iPhone Application, the PHP script then returns a yes or no depending on wether the credentials are correct or not, currently i am hard coding them, but they don't seem to be operating as expected, even though the PHP script is returning yes, the conditional fails, I tried changing the result to a hard coded string and this worked...

Here is the code

```
NSString *varyingString1 = @"username=";
    NSString *varyingString2 = @"username";


    NSString *varyingString3 = @"&password=";
    NSString *varyingString4 = @"password";
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@%@", varyingString1, varyingString2, varyingString3, varyingString4];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/api/login.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *result = strResult;
    result = [post stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    if(result == @"yes"){
        NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"picker" sender:self];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
```

My web service written in PHP then looks like this

```
<?php if($_POST['password'] == 'password' && $_POST['username'] == 'username') echo "yes";
else echo "no";
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the value of "result" after running your code?

Comment: Using your debugger, examine the value saved to result.  You may have other whitespace characters that you aren't aware of within your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result == @"yes"` does not compare two strings.

To compare your strings use `[result isEqualToString:@"yes"]`

Answer (score -2):

for rest services its preferred to handle responses through http response code 
for exampel if the user logged in return 200 OK ,

if the credential failed return 401 Unauthorized 
then you can get the response body and handle it

```
   <?php 
   if($_POST['password'] == 'password' && $_POST['username'] == 'username') 
   {
    header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
   } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
   }
```

Comment: this is only the response header, and in the response body can return the message he needs , his rest api is not completed as you see.